# Firefox / Chrome - is there a plugin to click links with keyboard only?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I don't like having to switch from keyboard to mouse when I want to click a link on a page - I'm using a shortcut to bring up browser, `Ctrl-L` to print a search query, arrow keys to navigate to a search result, and `Enter` to open it. But on random websites I still have to touch the mouse to open a link.

I'm wondering if there is a plugin for one of the said browsers that does something along the lines of letting me press a button, e.g. `Ctrl`, which would assign the links currently visible on the page a single button (e.g. `1`,`2`,`3`), clicking on which would take me to the link target?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb) for Google Chrome (Chromium) will do the job for you.

Vimium also exists for Firefox, however [VimFx](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimfx/) has better reviews.

---

**Using Vimium**

*This is just one of several options available in Vimium. For a more comprehensive list, see [Vimium's ReadMe](https://github.com/philc/vimium/blob/master/README.md) on GitHub*.

- On any webpage, hit the <kbd>F</kbd> key on your keyboard

  - links on the page now have keyboard keys associated with it
- Enter the character or character combination to open the link

**Caveat**

- If the website (web application) you're using has keyboard shortcuts of its own, they may conflict with Vimium. So, you'll want to spend a little time tinkering with the options to suit your needs.

**Demo**

- Here, I'll open the `firefox` tag in your question above in a new tab.

[image: Demo of using Vimium to open link in a new tab]